# Accessing the node.js, mongo DB in server LAN via public Apache server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apache, express

We are a developing a project in which our client has hosted a public IP Apache server which has got htaccess. All other servers node.js, mongoDB etc are behind this Apache server but in Local LAN of the apache server. These inner servers are not accessible directly to outside world. 
So the question arises now how to access REST(nodejs) APIs that we shall be calling from ReactNative application?
We will using some WinSCP tool to send our js files from our desktop to Apache server then will internally transfer to nodejs server.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Apache ProxyPass / ProxyPassReverse to forward request from Apache to Nodejs